# Newton's method: convergence

Tags: real-analysis, newton-raphson

> Suppose $f$ is differentiable in the interval $[a,b]$ and $x_0 \in
>  [a,b]$. Given the Newton's method sequence
> $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$, with $x_n \in [a,b] \forall n$,show that if the sequence $x_n
> \rightarrow r$, then $f(r)=0$

The hypothesis given are really sufficient to prove this statement? What I could do so far is the following:

$\lim x_{n+1}=r=\lim \left [x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \right ]$

But I don't know how to proceed if $f'$ is not continuous.

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity, so there's no issue.

Comment: $f$ is indeed continuous, but it does not guarantee $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: No, you need something like $f'$ to be bounded and bounded away from zero in a neighbourhood of $r$.

Comment: With @copper.hat's assumption, just write $$f(x_n)=f'(x_n)(x_n-x_{n+1})$$ and take the limit as $n$ tends to $+\infty$.